# How to manually stop velocity in the Phaser framework?

Tags: phaser-framework

I am trying to manually stop gravity after a manual collision test. I can successfully test the collision, however when I set velocity to zero, the player continues to "sink" under gravity, albeit much slower than just gravity - hence "sinking".

```
// note that this is babel
update() {
    this.player.body.velocity.y = 0;
}
```

How do you set velocity y to zero within update and actually cease the sprite from continuing to move, albeit slowly, due to gravity?

I am a sneaking suspicion that update is called less frequently than the internal physics update cycle? But I could be wrong.

Comment: Can't you set the player velocity to zero from within the function that detects the collision?

Comment: I am, but that is called within the update loop. So I removed it show that it has nothing to do with the collision itself, but rather setting velocity to zero

Comment: can you please post the full code that will be more easier to debug

Comment: That is the full code. Using the above on the standard Phaser sprite will show it "sinking" through space